# Problem with position of table using sidewaystable environment

Tags: tables, positioning, rotating

I am using the `sidewaystable` environment to rotate a table and its caption. My problem is that when compiling, there is a blank space at the bottom of the page and the table is moved to the top, colliding with the section header. I am using the `rotating` package; here is the code I use for this large table.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}\centering%
\begin{tabular}{ccp{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}}
\hline\hline
\textbf{Copula} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{%
Estimator}} \\ 
True $\lambda _{L}$ &  &  & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ & 
lambda3 & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ & $\lambda
_{L,n}^{ers}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{ers,r}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{CHT}$ & $\lambda
_{L,n}^{CHT,r}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{AM}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{GM}$ & $\lambda
_{L,n}^{rank}$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{(U,U)(e)}$ \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Comparison of the true tail dependence coefficient implied by the
parametric copula models, in the case of}%
\end{sidewaystable}\centering%
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: note that the rotating package merely puts  the rotated box into a standard page: it leaves things like page decorations there.  the blank space i see at the bottom comes from the figure being placed higher than the page number.  this may be different for you, but you posted no working example.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\resizebox` to scale the table; additionally, you could also reduce `\tabcolsep` which controls the spacing between columns (default=`6pt`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\resizebox{\textheight}{!}{
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccp{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}}
  \hline\hline
  \textbf{Copula} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{Estimator}} \\ 
  True $\lambda _{L}$ &  &  & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ & $\lambda3$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ &
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ &   $\lambda_{L,n}^{ers}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{ers,r}$ & $\lambda_{L,n}^{CHT}$ &  
    $\lambda_{L,n}^{CHT,r}$ & $\lambda   _{L,n}^{AM}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{GM}$ & $\lambda_{L,n}^{rank}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{(U,U)(e)}$ \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}}%
\caption{Comparison of the true tail dependence coefficient implied by the
parametric copula models, in the case of}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

To improve the quality of your tables, you could be interested in the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.

Taking into account the comment, the intention seems to be just to shift the table downwards (which couldn't be the best option); to achieve this, an appropriate skip can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\hspace*{-3cm}
\begin{tabular}{ccp{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}p{0.45in}}
  \hline\hline
  \textbf{Copula} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{13}{c}{\textbf{Estimator}} \\ 
  True $\lambda _{L}$ &  &  & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ & $\lambda3$ & $\lambda _{L,n}^{e}$ &
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{e,r}$ &   $\lambda_{L,n}^{ers}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{ers,r}$ & $\lambda_{L,n}^{CHT}$ &  
    $\lambda_{L,n}^{CHT,r}$ & $\lambda   _{L,n}^{AM}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{GM}$ & $\lambda_{L,n}^{rank}$ & 
    $\lambda _{L,n}^{(U,U)(e)}$ \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Comparison of the true tail dependence coefficient implied by the
parametric copula models, in the case of}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, basically what you're seeing is what I see with the blank space. The problem is that I want the table to stay as it is, I just need to shift it downwards, I tried using vskip and hskip, but for some reason it would only let me move it horizontally but not vertically, thanks

Comment: @JuanLuisLopezHernandez: if you just want to shift the table, replace the `\resizebox` command and the redefinition of `\tabcolsep` in my code with something like `\hspace*{-2cm}` (using the length that best serves your purpose); see my updated answer.